# Updating Firebase Database with nodes created with push

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to update a value in my Firebase database. This is the structure of the database:

[image]

I need to update the value of `status` to `"accepted"` if the `r_id` and `s_id` have a specific value. The problem here is that the key for each `friend_data` child is generated using "push" like this

```
db.child("friend_data").push().setValue(friend);
```

I have tried [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38301310/firebase-how-to-update-data-at-a-key) and [this one here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41731924/how-to-update-a-specific-node-from-a-firebase-database-with-android) but both don't meet my requirements. How do I go about solving this one?

**Edit:** I understand now that I am supposed to use a `Query` here. This is what I tried:

```
final DatabaseReference db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("friend_data");

Query query = db.orderByChild("r_id").equalTo(f_id).orderByChild("s_id").equalTo(id);
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            db.child(child.getKey()).child("status").setValue("accepted");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

This does not work either because this error is raised

**java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You can't combine multiple orderBy calls!**.

So how do I combine two Queries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have finally got this to work after days of trying to figure it out.

I added a Query with `orderByChild` method to filter out a big chunk of data at the server side itself (thanks to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26701282/6891637) for the idea.) The remaining data which I got as `child` of data type `DataSnapshot` had all the necessary information that I needed. Here is the query

```
Query query = db.orderByChild("r_id").equalTo(f_id);
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String child_s_id = (String) child.child("s_id").getValue();
            String child_status = (String) child.child("status").getValue();

            if (child_s_id.equals(id)) {
                Log.e("Got value", f_id + " - x -" + id + " " + child_status);

            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

But again I could not meet my requirements, because I actually needed to modify one of the value in the `child` and I could not use any methods like `setValue` to change the value of `child`.

Again, it took me a long while (what an idiot) to figure out that I had to convert the `child` (of data type `DataSnapShot`) to a reference for `setValue` to work. And it worked

```
child.getRef().child("status").setValue("accepted");
```

Here is the completed code. Hope it helps someone along the way

```
Query query = db.orderByChild("r_id").equalTo(f_id);
query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String child_s_id = (String) child.child("s_id").getValue();
            String child_status = (String) child.child("status").getValue();

            if (child_s_id.equals(id))
                child.getRef().child("status").setValue("accepted");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```